# How to maintain state of android activity

Tags: android-widget

I am new to android.I created an activity in which i add text view dynamically on button click event.After adding text view i click home button of my phone.When i start the application after 1 or 2 hour the added text view is disappeared.Kindly help me out to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That probably means that your application has been terminated at some point by Android.
Even if you press the Home button leaving the app running in background, it can be killed by the system if it needs to free resources.

Here's how to use SharedPreferences to save the application status and restore it once the app is restarted: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: Thanks for your reply brother.Is there any way to prevent system to kill the application/activity?

Comment: As far as I know you can't. If the system needs more resources it can kill your app (if it is in background) at any time. Have a look at the link I posted, you can save your app status and the restore it on restart.